# very low accuracy neural network with pybrain

Tags: neural-network, pybrain

I just started learn machine learning using python and I am building a neural network with pybrain to train digit recognition problem. I finally got the program work however the accuracy is very low (~30%) on both training and test set. I think there must be something wrong but I couldn't find the problem. I have been stuck here for days. Can anyone help me out? Thanks a lot.

each training data: input is 28*28 grayscale, reshaped into 1*784, output is 1*10 array with 0 or 1 with the location 1 indicating the digit, for example
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0] means the digit is 7.

Here is the code:

```
from pybrain.datasets.supervised import SupervisedDataSet as SDS
from pybrain.tools.shortcuts import buildNetwork
from pybrain.supervised.trainers import BackpropTrainer
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

#build datasets
size_sample = 500
#randomly choose 500 training data    
(sample_X,sample_y) = randomSample(training_X, training_y, size_sample)
ds = SDS(28*28,10)
ds.setField( 'input', sample_X )
#sample_y = sample_y.reshape(size_sample,10)
ds.setField( 'target', sample_y )
#build network
Num_Hidden_Layers = 10
net = buildNetwork(ds.indim,Num_Hidden_Layers,ds.outdim,bias=True,outclass=SoftmaxLayer)
#train data
trainer = BackpropTrainer(net,ds)

# predict using test data
print "Making predictions..."
predict_y = []
for i in range(test_X.shape[0]):
    pred = net.activate(test_X[i, :])
    print pred
    print pred.argmax()
    predict_y = np.append(predict_y, pred.argmax())
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're not actually using 10 hidden layers, you're using just 10 hidden units. (http://pybrain.org/docs/quickstart/network.html) Try this instead:

```
    buildNetwork(ds.indim,25, 50, 25,ds.outdim,bias=True,outclass=SoftmaxLayer)
```

If that works to give a better output accuracy then you know you're on the right track at which point you just have to play around with the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Resilient Backpropagation trainer (Rprop). This should train you network way better.